# Preferred pattern for constructing command objects when using command pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

We are trying to apply the command pattern to one of our projects. Every command object has a different kind and number of parameters. Which pattern would lend itself best for creating these command objects? I am currently looking into abstract factory and builder pattern. I am still an amateur in design patterns. Can someone recommend a pattern that would be most appropriate for my requirements?

Comment: You can create a singleton factory which you construct the commands. The difficulty is actually setting the parameters. You could potentially  just use a map and a simple interface, or create a factory to give you a specific parameter object for your command.

Comment: Provide more details about the attributes of the commands, are they all required, do the commands have many constructors, do the commmands share the same sets of parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is not traditionally a pattern used for creating commands. Here's the UML of the Command Pattern:

[image: Command pattern in UML]

As you can see above, `Client` is directly coupled to `ConcreteCommand` and the pattern even says it creates them.

> Every command object has a different kind and number of parameters.

This detail will make it difficult to decouple the object creation from your client code.

One simple way is to use a so-called [Simple Factory (aka Concrete Factory)](http://corey.quickshiftconsulting.com/blog/first-post).

[image: Simple Factory pattern with Command pattern]

The intention here is to encapsulate creation of Commands by using a `CommandFactory.createCommand(...)` method. Client code doesn't want to know the details of `new CommandA(...)`, etc.

However, **since the constructor for each concrete Command has different parameters, you'd need the client to supply that information to the `createCommand(...)` method**. In my opinion, this pattern wouldn't provide much benefit, because the Client has to provide almost the same amount of details with or without the pattern. It might be good if you didn't want the Client to know the exact names of the ConcreteCommands.

For example, without the Simple Factory pattern, `Client` would have to do `new CommandA(arg1, arg2)` (direct coupling to the concrete command). With the Simple Factory pattern, `Client` would have to do `CommandFactory.createCommand("A", arg1, arg2)`, where "A" (or something similar) is the discriminant for the ConcreteCommand to create. If you added a `CommandD` to your design, `Client` would still need to change (it would have to call `createCommand("D", ...)`) *and* you'd have to update `CommandFactory`. Seems like a lot of complexity for little benefit.

Using a Factory Method or Abstract Factory pattern seems even more complicated, but your question doesn't supply enough detail to really know for sure.